# Changing bitmap brightness fast

Tags: android, bitmap

I have two bitmaps in size 1080 * 1080 and 3000 * 3000, I wanted to change the brightness of the bitmaps and I was successful but the problem is that I do this with the seekbar, it does a lot of work, its size is over 1080 * 1080 because it is 3000 * 3000 bitmaps . The brightness changes rapidly, but sometimes even the 1080 * 1080 bitmap flickers, but the 60 * 60 size bitmap changes the brightness very quickly,

My question is how can I quickly change the brightness of a high dimensional bitmap like with image editors?

Brightness code link; [Click to see the code](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/05/adjust-brightness-of-bitmap.html?m=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities to achieve that :

**RECOMMENDED :**

1. Use **[GPUImage for Android](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage)** :

**XML :**

```
<jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage.GPUImageView
    android:id="@+id/gpuimageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**JAVA :**

```
private SeekBar seekBarBrightness;
private float brightnessOpacity = 50.0f;
private GPUImageView mGPUImageView;

     seekBarBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

                brightnessOpacity = (float) i;
                mGPUImageView.setFilter(new GPUImageBrightnessFilter(range((int) brightnessOpacity , -0.5f, 0.5f));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

   protected static float range(int percentage, float start, float end) {
        return (((end - start) * ((float) percentage)) / 100.0f) + start;
    }
```

2. Using your current code : (this will produce an **Out Of Memory exception** if the image too large)

To prevent the lag issue, replace the code inside `onProgressChanged` method to `onStopTrackingTouch` method.

```
seekBarBrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              //YOUR CODE HERE
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a very important problem for me.

Comment: I did some research but could not find your usage on sites, is there a link you can give me on how I can use all the filters?

Comment: @AnonimSorry but you asked for brightness, right, if you want to implement more filters, please ask another question, I will gladly help you

Comment: Can you look at this question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63366559/how-to-using-gpuimage)